# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when using rename() function

Tags: php

With PHP I am trying to move a picture from one folder to another. In my photo processing script, when I use rename(), I get the following error message in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My rename function is something like this for example:

```
rename("../../uploads/temp/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-19-12.jpeg", "../../uploads/final/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-19-12.jpeg");
```

I already changed the permissions for the folders "temp" and "final" to 777, but still I get this problem.

Here comes my full code:

```
<?php

/************************************************
 * The Croppic Img Crop To File PHP
 * - goal: cropping the image
 ************************************************/

/* saves cropped image to "temp" folder
* possible GET parameters:
* - subfolder  -->  contains name of group: users, adverts
*/

session_start();

include '../db.php';
include '../functions.php';

// receive image data
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];

// set image quality
$jpeg_quality = 100;

// define output name
$folderUploads = '../../uploads/';
$tempParentDir = $folderUploads . 'temp/' . $_GET['subfolder'] . '/';
$finalParentDir = $folderUploads . 'final/' . $_GET['subfolder'] . '/';

// if user folder does not exist create one
$parentDirWithUserFolder = $tempParentDir . getUserId($db);
if (!is_dir($parentDirWithUserFolder)) {
    // Check if the parent directory is a directory
    if (!is_dir($tempParentDir)) {
        die('Invalid path specified');
    }
    // Check if the parent directory is writeable
    if (!is_writable($tempParentDir)) {
        die('Unable to create directory, permissions denied.');
    }
    // Create the directory
    if (mkdir($parentDirWithUserFolder) === false) {
        die('Problems creating directory.');
    }
}

// make sure only specific types of images get uploaded
$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);
switch (strtolower($what['mime'])) {
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default:
        die('image type not supported');
}

$pathForDb = getUserId($db) . "/photo-user-" . getUserId($db) . "-" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
$output_filename = $tempParentDir . $pathForDb;

$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);

$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $resizedImage, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);

imagejpeg($dest_image, $output_filename . $type, $jpeg_quality);

// move photo file from temp folder to final folder
$sourcePath = $output_filename . $type;
$finalPath = $finalParentDir . $pathForDb . $type;
rename($sourcePath, $finalPath);

$response = array(
    "status" => 'success',
    "url" => $output_filename . $type
);

print json_encode($response);

?>
```

This script works perfectly when WITHOUT the rename function.

Here comes the response the file provides under "Network":

```
<b>Warning</b>:  rename(../../uploads/temp/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-41-26.jpeg,../../uploads/final/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-41-26.jpeg): No such file or directory in <b>/home/www/system/process-image-upload/process-image-save-to-temp.php</b> on line <b>94</b><br />
```

The file definitely exists, i looked it up on the server. I use rename($value1, $value2)...

Comment: Use `quotes` around each parameter of `rename` function. Like: `rename('param1', 'param2')`

Comment: sorry, I forget the quotes. I use variables and they translate for example to the paths i provide in my post. so when using rename($path1, $path2) I still get this problem...

Comment: Seems like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` is a JS error message. Are you trying to parse the response using JS? Head over to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571482/parsing-php-response-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token). The client error might be caused by an error / warning message generated by the server. Use the debugging tools of your browser to intercept the server response and check whether it differs from what you expected.

Comment: Please show more code. The problem will be on other line, where you used `<`.

Comment: @panther Not necessarily. `Uncaught SyntaxError` seems to be a JS error ("in my console"), resulting from a PHP warning / error message.

Comment: I just added the full code to my post...

Comment: Yeah, seems like I was right. See my above comments for instructions.

Comment: @still_learning: Thank you, i looked up the response under "Networks" and the response of my file is the following: <b>Warning</b>:  rename(../../uploads/temp/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-41-26.jpeg,../../uploads/final/users/15/photo-user-15-2015-01-31-13-41-26.jpeg): No such file or directory in <b>/home/www/system/process-image-upload/process-image-save-to-temp.php</b> on line <b>94</b><br /> But how can this be? The file to be moved definitely exists on the server... I use rename($value1, $value2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving a file from `$tempParentDir` to `$finalParentDir` but you check whether the source directory exists, not the destination directory. The error message you got means that the destination directory does not exist. You need to change your code so that it ensures the destination directory exists, not the source directory (which always exists as you know there is a file in it).

I think you just have to change this:

```
// if user folder does not exist create one
$parentDirWithUserFolder = $tempParentDir . getUserId($db);
if (!is_dir($parentDirWithUserFolder)) {
    // Check if the parent directory is a directory
    if (!is_dir($tempParentDir)) {
        die('Invalid path specified');
    }
    // Check if the parent directory is writeable
    if (!is_writable($tempParentDir)) {
        die('Unable to create directory, permissions denied.');
    }
    // Create the directory
    if (mkdir($parentDirWithUserFolder) === false) {
        die('Problems creating directory.');
    }
}
```

Replace

```
$parentDirWithUserFolder = $tempParentDir . getUserId($db);
```

with

```
$parentDirWithUserFolder = $finalParentDir . getUserId($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rename probably throws an `Exception`, either the file you try to `rename` does not exist or you do not have permissions necessary for the operation at your folder. Try testing with this code:

```
try {
    rename($sourcePath, $finalPath);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo var_dump($e);
}
```

look at the error message in your network at the given request, fix the problem and get the test code (echoing `var_dump`) out.